# How to target my h2 heading in drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is target my H2 tag. How can I achieve this?
What I want to do is hide my second h2 tag. Thanks Stackoverflow!

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="nav1"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav2"><a href="#">Member Solutions</a>
    <div class="subMenu"  >
      <ul>
        <li class="sectionTitle">
          <h2><a href="#">Example Head</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li class="sectionTitle">
            <h2><a href="#">Hide this h2 tag</a></h2>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Umbrella Insurance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="navLast"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide based on an index, use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$("#nav h2").eq(1).hide();
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsh5Z/)

Comment: Nifty.  I would have `$($('#nav h2').get(1)).hide();`, I didn't know about the `eq()` operator.

Comment: that would hide all my first h2 tags wouldn't it? @Digital Planes method worked because i targeted the h2 tag according the index of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
myH2Tags = $("div.submenu").find("h2");
$(myH2Tags).get(1).hide();
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  `.get()` returns the DOM object, not a jQuery object; I don't think you can chain `hide()` to it.

Comment: I checked the manual of jquery and I saw my mistake. I mixed it up with eq(). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hideThis = $('ul li.sectiontitle').find('h2');

$(hideThis).hide();
```